# Parent re-rendering after next state change

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux and I appear to be having an issue. Once my action has been dispatched it is successful however the parent component does not get the updated state until another state change is made. If I click login then delete a character in the input field the state change is then triggered showing me the Menu. Any help/pointers are much appreciated, thanks.

Main (Parent):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Login from '../login'
import Menu from '../menu'

type Props = { token: string }
class Main extends Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    const { token } = this.props;

    if (!token) {
      return (
        <Login />
      )
    }

    return (
      <Menu />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  token: state.session.token,
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
)(Main)
```

Login (Child):

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { login } from '../../redux/session/session.actions'

import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Button, FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage } from 'react-native-elements'

import styled from 'styled-components/native'

const Container = styled(View)`
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`

const Wrapper = styled(View)`
    width: 300;
`

type Props = { login: Function, error: string, loading: boolean };
type State = { email: string, password: string };

class Login extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: null,
            password: null,
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log('props', this.props);
        console.log('state', this.state);
        const { loading, error } = this.props;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Wrapper>
                    <FormValidationMessage>{loading ? 'Loading...' : null}</FormValidationMessage>
                    <FormValidationMessage>{error ? 'Unable to login, please try again.' : null}</FormValidationMessage>
                    <FormLabel>Email:</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput onChangeText={text => this.setState({ email: text })} />
                    <FormLabel>Password:</FormLabel>
                    <FormInput secureTextEntry onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })} />
                    <Button title='Login' onPress={this.login} />
                </Wrapper>
            </Container>
        )
    }

    login = () => {
        this.props.login(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        error: state.session.error,
        loading: state.session.loading
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ({
   login
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);
```

Reducer:

```
import {
    LOGGING_IN,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAILED
  } from './session.types'

  const initialState = {
    loading: null,
    error: null,
    token: null,
  }

  export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {

      case LOGGING_IN:
        return { 
          ...state, 
          loading: true
        }

      case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        return { 
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          token: payload.token
        }

      case LOGIN_FAILED:
        return { 
          ...state, 
          loading: false,
          error: payload.error  
        }

      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

Actions:

```
import { API_URL } from '../../../app-env'
import axios from 'axios'

import {
  LOGGING_IN,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAILED
} from './session.types'

export const login = (email, password) => (
  async dispatch => {
    console.log('here');
    dispatch(loggingIn());

    await axios.post(`${API_URL}/login`, {
      email,
      password
    }).then(res => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data.token))
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch(loginFailed('Unable to login.'))
    })
  }
)

export const loggingIn = () => ({
  type: LOGGING_IN,
})

export const loginSuccess = (token) => ({
  type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  payload: {
    token
  }
})

export const loginFailed = (error) => ({
  type: LOGIN_FAILED,
  payload: {
    error
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is about `Menu` not render and `Menu` is under `Main`. So, we can ask the question what condition `Main` component not re-render. Luckily your example `Main` only depend on solely one props and no state. -I'll say your problem lies on props.token.- Since you initialize your token as `null`, I'll assume it hold object type. In that case, you need to make sure the token need to be a new object (new reference) else no re-render because react-redux `connect` by default will check the props changes before trigger the component underneath it.

EDIT: You mentioned the `Menu` not showing and the token is string, I can think of another reason `Main` not render is because `connect` is not trigger. You probably need to check the root of the store and make sure it has the new reference as your code only showing the reducer update state.session but not the state itself.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Token is storing a JWT string. if its null then I am conditionally rendering the login page, else I want to show the menu. I have attached my actions to the question if that helps. It is just returning the token string in the new state. I get the token, only after the next state change. If I click login after entering valid creds I then have to make a state change in the login component (done by editing any input field) for the parent to update the state.

Comment: Is it possible to have your root reducer show here too? The store. The reference of store may be not changing though I not 100% sure that if that's needed for the state update on container component (`connect`).